# Restlet 1001 after adding Header

Tags: http-headers, cors, restlet, restlet-2.0

I was trying to add some headers to allow for CORS, it worked pretty well before, but this time it gives me an Restlet1001 connector error with the identical code

```
    Form responseHeaders = addHeader((Form) getResponse().getAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers")); 
    if (responseHeaders != null){
        getResponse().getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders); 
    }
```

so this is the code that calls the add header method, the add header method is:

```
public static Form addHeader(Form responseHeaders){
    if (responseHeaders == null) { 
        responseHeaders = new Form(); 
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authCode");
        responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, x-requested-with, content-type");
        return responseHeaders;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After quite some try&error and Google, I still have no idea why it gives me:

```
2013-07-07  19:39:24    127.0.0.1   -   -   8015    GET /api/v1.0/users/findSession -   200 -   0   159 http://localhost:8015   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36    -
2013-07-07  19:39:24    127.0.0.1   -   -   8015    GET /api/v1.0/users/findSession -   1001    -   0   1   http://localhost:8015   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36    -
2013-07-07  19:39:24    127.0.0.1   -   -   8015    GET /api/v1.0/users/findSession -   1001    -   0   1   http://localhost:8015   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36    -
```

Answer (score 0):

Which of Restlet and HTTP connector did you use? Perhaps can you make a try with the simple or jetty connector if you use the internal one of Restlet.